# Se pierde los dpi de la imagen al bajar la resolucion

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código. que lo que hace es tomar una imagen y bajarle la resolución por que necesito que pese menos. pero el problema es que se pierde los ppp o dpi originales de 200 a 1 y deben conservar los mismos al bajar de resolución

```
public void resize(InputStream input, OutputStream output, int width, int height) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage src = ImageIO.read(input);
    BufferedImage dest = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = dest.createGraphics();

    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getScaleInstance((double)width / src.getWidth(), (double)height / src.getHeight());
    g.drawRenderedImage(src, at);
    ImageIO.write(dest, "tif", output);
    output.close();
}
```

como podria hacer esto?

Imagen comprimida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen antes de bajar las dimensiones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si bajas la resolución, se pierde calidad, calidad que supongo no creo puede volver a restaurarse con algoritmos sencillos...

Comment: @usernovell Bajar la resolución **significa bajar los ppp (dpi)**

Answer (score 1):

Resolución es el numero de pixeles contenidos en una imagen.
Te doy un ejemplo, si tenemos una imagen de 1080x800 pixeles tendríamos una resolución de 864,000 pixeles, si realizas una transformación con menor tamaño tendrias una resolución menor.

Recomiendo uses otro método para reducir el peso de la imagen pero sin perder pixeles.

[Como redimensionar una imagen sin perder calidad.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160919042503/http://www.fotolinux.org:80/programacion/java/redimensionar-una-imagen-en-java/)

```
public static BufferedImage resize(BufferedImage bufferedImage, int newW, int newH) {
    int w = bufferedImage.getWidth();
    int h = bufferedImage.getHeight();
    BufferedImage imagenRedimensionada = new BufferedImage(newW, newH, bufferedImage.getType());
    Graphics2D g = imagenRedimensionada.createGraphics();
    g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, newW, newH, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g.dispose();
    return imagenRedimensionada;
}
```

Comment: Mira subí unas imágenes de lo que me esta pasando probé tu código y me pasa lo mismo, que puedo hacer para que no me baje la resolución tanto horizontal como vertical. (ppp) aclaro: no puedo trabajar otro formato se me exige .tif.

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a mantener la resolución "fisica" de los pixels (DPI), eso es considerado parte de la "metadata" de las imagenes, y el soporte que da la API de Java ImageIO para esas cosas es limitado. Y más aun en el caso del formato TIF, que es menos soportado que los más populares (JPEG y PNG). Te recomiendo pasarte a PNG si puedes, y te paso algunos links (en inglés) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321736/how-to-set-dpi-information-in-an-image)  [2](http://youcmini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/03/java-tiff-dpi.html) [3](http://www.java-forums.org/java-2d/54783-tiff-dpi-scale.html)